# Ошибка LNK2001 Помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты и просто люди шарящие в c++!
    У меня есть ряд ошибок с кодом LNK2001 :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код файла GUI.cpp содержит 1000 с лишним строк поэтому я вставлю часть с билиотеками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот весь код файла Kvadrasense.cpp
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в config.cpp больше 1500 файлов скину только libы :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Помогите пожалуйста, скажите как исправить, если нужна серьёзная работа над кодом напишите мне)***

Comment: Где Config.cpp?

Comment: Уже добавил)  config.cpp